# Split text file into 2 files by separator

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am looking for a simple batch script that split my text file into two files. The text file is separated by with

```
============================================================================
```

Text file looks like this:

```
test
test1
test2
test5
test
test1
test2
test5
============================================================================
test
test1
test2
test5
test
test1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "file=file.txt"
for /f "delims=[]" %%i in ('^<"%file%" find /n "="') do set "split=%%i"
(for /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%i in ('^<"%file%" find /n /v ""') do if %%i lss %split% echo(%%j)>"%file%.new1"
<"%file%">"%file%.new2" more +%split%
type "%file%.new?"
```

..output is:

```
file.txt.new1


test
test1
test2
test5
test
test1
test2
test5

file.txt.new2


test
test1
test2
test5
test
test1
```

Comment: I try to run this batch file but when I execute it, it hangs. I have to terminate it when I want to stop the executing.

Comment: This is a "bug" in `findstr`, your input file must end with a `CR/LF` on the very last line.

Comment: I made an edit, the code now uses `find` and I hope, this will work for you.

Comment: What if I want to split file by words not a full line?

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
set /p file=FILE TO PROCESS : 
del /q /f out.file*
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set out_file_counter=1
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%file%") do (
 set line=%%L
 if "!line:~0,5!" equ "=====" (
    set /a out_file_counter=out_file_counter+1

 ) else (
   echo !line!>>out.file.!out_file_counter!
  )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I run this file, I'm not get any output.

Comment: you should change `(myfile.txt)` with your file path...

Comment: I've changed the script a little bit to be more easier for use