# Batch - split html file when matching string is found

Tags: html, batch-file

I have 1 html file which contains 2 separate html file in it. I want to write a batch file that look for tag , and split original html in 2 html files.

This is what I tried

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
set c=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (split.html) do (
if "%%a" equ "</html>" (
set /a c+=1
>f!c!.html echo.
) else (
>> f!c!.html echo( %%a)
)
)
```

In html file, there's `!` character, but in output file all of them are missing. How do keep `!` in the output file?

Thanks

**Update 26-07-2015** I got answer from here. Thank you all for your help. [Split text file into 2 files by separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603225/split-text-file-into-2-files-by-separator)

```
@echo off
set /p file=FILE TO PROCESS : 
del /q /f out.file*
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set out_file_counter=1
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%file%") do (
 set line=%%L
 if "!line:~0,5!" equ "=====" (
    set /a out_file_counter=out_file_counter+1

 ) else (
   echo !line!>>out.file.!out_file_counter!
  )
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the second line, it disabled `!` variables.
2. To correctly output `!` characters inside html disable the expansion inside the loop:

   ```
   @echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   set c=0
   for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (split.html) do (
       if "%%a" equ "</html>" (
           set /a c+=1
           >f!c!.html echo.
       ) else (
           >> f!c!.html (
               ENDLOCAL
               echo %%a
               SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
           )
       )
   )
   ```

Comment: In html file there is `!` character, but the output is missing all of them. I think it's `enabledelayedexpansion `

Comment: Well, you can disable it inside the loop, see the updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
call :SplitFile < split.html > split-1.html
goto :EOF

:SplitFile
   set "line="
   set /P "line="
   set /P "=%line%" < NUL
   echo/
   if "%line%" equ "</html>" (
      rem Copy the rest of lines to part 2 and terminate
      findstr "^" > split-2.html
      exit /B
   )
goto SplitFile
```

Comment: I got error at line 3 `The syntax of the command is incorrect`. Thanks

Comment: Please, insert a `REM` before the first `@echo off`, run the Batch file and post _the whole line_ that appear _below_ the error messsage. As far as I know, Batch file errors are _not_ reported with line numbers...

Comment: The bat just stopped at line 3. Here's error message http://prntscr.com/7x3khf. I have used your latest version

Comment: I tested my code and it works correctly. The problem you reported is _very unsual_. Perhaps you may be interested in know what is happening here, because you may get a similar problem afterward. Note: in batch files the error message appear _first_ and _below it_ appear the offending line. This is the reason because I say that your problem is _very unusual_!

Answer (score 0):

I got answer from here. Thank you all for your help. [Split text file into 2 files by separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603225/split-text-file-into-2-files-by-separator)

```
@echo off
set /p file=FILE TO PROCESS : 
del /q /f out.file*
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set out_file_counter=1
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%file%") do (
 set line=%%L
 if "!line:~0,5!" equ "=====" (
    set /a out_file_counter=out_file_counter+1

 ) else (
   echo !line!>>out.file.!out_file_counter!
  )
)
endlocal
```